# I am having persistent Vue Warns about an unknown "custom element" that should and has in the past functioned

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs3

My tdhPermissions and Biometricos Components produce this error:

mainApp.js:43 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app-biometricos> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)

with their respective names in the following "app".

This error seemed to come out of nowhere while debugging other issues. I have triple-checked all of the names in my app and they all line up as they should.

Below I will include my Index.vue, Modal.vue and TableHelpers.js files for tdhPermissions(biometricos is not yet finished) and my index.blade for biomentricos which is identical to that of tdhPermissions

Index.vue:

```js
<template>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <app-breadcrumb :page-title="('tdhPermissions')"/>
            </div>    
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 breadcrumb-side-button">
                <div class="fload-md-right mb-3 mb-sm-3 mb-md-0">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-with-shadow"
                            data-toggle="modal"
                            @click="openAddEditModal">
                        {{  $t('add') }}    
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <app-table :id="'tdhPermissions-table'" :options="options"/>
            <app-tdhPermissions-modal v-if="isAddEditModalActive"
                       :table-id="tableId"
                       :selected-url="selectedUrl"
                       @close-modal="closeAddEditModal"/> 
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import * as actions from "../../../Config/ApiUrl";
    import {TableHelpers} from "./TableHelpers";
    export default {
        name: "ResponsiveDatatable",
        mixins:[TableHelpers],
        data() {
            return {
                //responsiveDatatableInstruction: [this.$t('esta nota podran verla')],
                deleteLoader: false,
                isAddEditModalActive: false,
                deleteConformationModalActive: false,
                selectedUrl: '',
                tableId: '',
                rowData: {},

                options: {
                    name: 'tdhPermissions-table',
                    isAddEditModalActive: false,
                    url: `${actions.tdhPermissions}/index`,
                    showHeader: true,
                    columns: [],
                    datatableWrapper: false,
                    showFilter: false,
                    showSearch: false,
                    showAction: false,
                    actions:[],
                    paginationType: "pagination",
                    responsive: true,
                    rowLimit: 10,
                    orderBy: 'desc',
                }
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.options.columns = [...this.tableColumns];
        },
        methods: {
            openAddEditModal() {
                this.isAddEditModalActive = true;
            },
            closeAddEditModal() {
                $("#demo-add-edit-Modal").modal('hide');
                this.isAddEditModalActive = false;
                this.reSetData();
            },
            reSetData() {
                this.rowData = {};
                this.selectedUrl = '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<template>
    <modal :modal-id="modalId" :title="modalTitle" :preloader="preloader" @submit="submit" @close-modal="closeModal">
        <template slot="body">
            <app-overlay-loader v-if="preloader" />
            <form class="mb-0" :class="{ 'loading-opacity': preloader }" ref="form" 
                :data-url='selectedUrl 
                ? `masterdata/tdhPermissions/${inputs.id}` 
                : `masterdata/tdhPermissions`'>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('permission_date') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="date"
                               v-model="inputs.permission_date"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('permissions_start_date') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="date"
                               v-model="inputs.permissions_start_date"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('permissions_start_time') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="time"
                               v-model="inputs.permissions_start_time"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_time')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('permissions_end_date') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="date"
                               v-model="inputs.permissions_end_date"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('permissions_end_time') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="time"
                               v-model="inputs.permissions_end_time"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_time')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label for="inputs_name" class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('Justification') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input id="inputs_name" class="col-sm-9" type="textarea" 
                        v-model="inputs.justification"
                        :placeholder="$t('textarea_field')" :required="true" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center " > <!--stlye="margin bottom: x px;"-->
                    <label class="col-sm-3 mb-0">
                        {{ $t('Approval') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-9"
                               type="radio"
                               v-model="inputs.is_approve"
                               :list="activeLists"/>
                </div>
                 
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center ">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 mb-0">
                        {{ $t('Estado') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-9"
                               type="radio"
                               v-model="inputs.is_active"
                               :list="activeLists"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </template>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
import { FormMixin } from '../../../../core/mixins/form/FormMixin';
import AppLibrary from '../../../Helpers/AppLibrary';
import { ModalMixin } from '../../../Mixins/ModalMixin';

export default {
    name: "tdhPermissionsModal",
    extends: AppLibrary,
    mixins: [FormMixin, ModalMixin],
    props: {
        tableId: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            preloader: false,
            inputs: {

            },
            activeLists: [
                    {id: '0', value: "Inactivo"},
                    {id: '1', value: "Activo"},
                ],
            modalId: 'tdhPermissions-edit-Modal',
            modalTitle: this.$t('Crear nuevas permissions'),
        }

    },
    created() {
        if (this.selectedUrl) {
            this.modalTitle = this.$t('edit');
            this.preloader = true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {

            this.save
                (this.inputs);
        },
        afterSuccess(response) {
            this.$toastr.s(response.data.message);
            this.$hub.$emit('reload-' + this.tableId);
        },

        afterSuccessFromGetEditData(response) {
            this.inputs = response.data;
            this.preloader = false;
        },
    },
}
</script> 

<style scoped>
.col-md-12{
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
</style>
```

```
            export const TableHelpers = { data() { return { tableColumns : [ { title: this.$t('id'), type: 'text', key: 'id',},
            {
                title: this.$t('permission_date'),
                type: 'date',
                key: 'permission_date',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('permission_start_date'),
                type: 'date',
                key: 'permission_start_date',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('permission_start_time'),
                type: 'dateTime',
                key: 'permission_start_time',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('permission_end_date'),
                type: 'dateTime',
                key: 'permission_end_date',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('permission_end_time'),
                type: 'dateTime',
                key: 'permission_end_time',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('justification'),
                type: 'String',
                key: 'justification',
        
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('is_approve'),
                type: 'custom-html',
                key: 'is_approve',
                isVisible: true,
                modifier: (value) => {

                    let ClassName = 'danger';

                    if (value === '1') ClassName = `success`;
                    else if (value === '0') ClassName = `warning`;

                    return `<span class="badge badge-sm badge-pill badge-${ClassName}">${this.$t(value)}</span>`;

                }
            },
            {
                title: this.$t('Estado'),
                type: 'custom-html',
                key: 'is_active',
                isVisible: true,
                modifier: (value) => {

                    let ClassName = 'danger';

                    if (value === '1') ClassName = `success`;
                    else if (value === '0') ClassName = `warning`;

                    return `<span class="badge badge-sm badge-pill badge-${ClassName}">${this.$t(value)}</span>`;

                }
            },
            
        ],
        actionObj : {
            title: this.$t('action'),
            type: 'action',
        }
    }
},
}
```

Index.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', trans('Biometricos'))

@section('contents')
\<app-biometricos\>\</app-biometricos\>
@endsection
```

This is my mainApp.js

```js
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
});
```

I have seen a lot of solutions suggesting global declaration of the components, but that does not seem to be the solution for me because they are already being declared in my AppComponents.js file:

```js
Vue.component('app-position', require('./Components/Views/Position/Index.vue').default)
Vue.component('app-position-modal', require('./Components/Views/Position/Modal.vue').default)

Vue.component('app-tdhPermissions', require('./Components/Views/TdhPermissions/Index.vue').default)
Vue.component('app-tdhPermissions-modal', require('./Components/Views/TdhPermissions/Modal.vue').default)

Vue.component('app-biometrics', require('./Components/Views/Biometricos/Index.vue').default)
Vue.component('app-biometrics-modal', require('./Components/Views/Biometricos/Modal.vue').default)
```

As you can see I also have a Position component, which works completely fine.

And just to prove that I have tried declaring my components globally, here is my mainApp.js.

```js
import './bootstrap';
import './plugins';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import vuexI18n from 'vuex-i18n';
import './core/coreApp';
import './app/AppComponents';
import './app/DemoComponent';


window.Vue = Vue;


import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll'
Vue.use(VueChatScroll)
/**
 * vuex
 */

Vue.use(Vuex);
import storeData from "./store/Index";
// import storeData from "./store/Index";
const store = new Vuex.Store(storeData);


/**
 * localization
 * $t('key') or this.$('key')
 * link: https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n
 * */

Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);

// add translations directly to the application
let language = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('app-languages'));
let key = window.localStorage.getItem('app-language');
Vue.i18n.add(key, language);
// set the start locale to use
Vue.i18n.set(key);

/*------ localization end ------*/
Vue.component('position', {

});
Vue.component('tdhPermissions', {
    props: {
        tableId: {
            type: String,
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('bioMetricos')

const app = new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#app',
    // data: {
    //     selectedUrl: '',
    //     tableId: '',
    // }
});
```

Comment: In your mainApp.js should register the global component before using it at index.blade. 
Refer: [Global Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration#Global-Registration)